# Is it possible to execute the value of an HTML textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create something that allows people to execute a line of JS. I want to convert the string that people type into a function to execute on the page using the  HTML tag

I've looked around and nothing is helping to this.

Comment: [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I guess we should remove the browser console / dev tools then.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol lol - ok, fair point :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval();`

example :

```
eval("console.log('hello')");
```

Comment: When recommending `eval()` there should always be a note about the security implications of doing so.

Comment: yeah getting script from input and run it directly by using eval without checking is secure the code or not 
it's a bad idea